# Executing cron in a time range

Tags: cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I have been searching but nothing resolved my question.

I have a cron job every 2 minutes (*/2 * * * * /example.sh) and I want the cron does not run in a time range, between 23:30 - 00:30

I have tried (30 00-23 * * * /example.sh) but It didn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you can either split the cronjob in different pieces or modify the script so that it checks the current time and exits if within 23.30-00.30 interval

Comment: @fedorqui comment will answer OP's question. afterall, i think it should have been `./example.sh` instead of `/example.sh`.